# Can windows authentication be used for database being accessed online?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, authentication, applet

I apologize if my question is confusing. I was wondering if windows authentication makes it difficult to access a MS SQL Server Database online? I currently have an applet that has a JTable filled with information from a MS SqL Server Database and it works fine in an IDE. However, when put in a browser, only the borders of the applet show up. Could this be because the authentication should be SQL Server Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 authentication issues to consider.

1) Making the website authenticate the users, you can use forms auth, or windows auth -- windows auth means users authenticate using their windows login and password for internal website use only, public facing internet site should not be using windows auth.

2) Making the web server authenticate against SQL server. If using Windows auth in part 1, you could impersonate the user and use integrated SQL login, but I've not seen a good use case for this. If your web server is dedicated to a single app, it might make sense to use the security context of the web server to make the Sql connection via an integrated login. But in reality I've never used it because in hosting envirnments it is pretty common for the database server and the web server to be in separate NT domains (esp. if the webservers are outside the firewall).

There are countless possible explanations for the behavior you describe, but I'm guessing you are concerned about the auth. issues.